# Does Crystal Reports store user / pwd in a report file?

Tags: .net-4.0, crystal-reports, iis-7.5

We have one report that when run throws an error stating "Database login failed". I have 20+ reports configured the same way that execute without any problems. In the Crystal Reports Designer, I verified the database and everything is good. The sql queries used to generate the report look good.

The reports are run from an ASP.NET application. We're not using a report server. We're using the 13.x runtime on the server. Reports are defined in CR Designer and passed parameters from the ASP.NET application.

Can Crystal store a username and password in the report file? How do I clear any saved values? Any other ideas? I'm a bit lost here since everything else is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Crystal can store authentication/connection info in the .rpt file. You can override this with your `ReportSource` definition by setting parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It most definitely does NOT store account/password in the RPT file.

You will need to explicitly set the authentication credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It does not store the password. It does store the ID most of the time. The reason some reports work sometimes has to do with if Windows authentication indicates you have access to the data.

The safest most consistent way to run reports is to use the ID/password evertime, although in some cases, if it's expecting Windows authentication only, putting the ID/password will cause it to fail.